# Как передать данные из FormArray в HttpParams?

Tags: angular2, typescript, angular

*Код проекта:* https://stackblitz.com/edit/rest-request-test-2

Есть FormArray:

```typescript
requestForm = this.fb.group({
    method: [null],
    baseUrl: [null],
    urlParams: new FormArray([
      new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl(null),
        value: new FormControl(null),
        mark: new FormControl(null)
      })
    ]),
    headerParams: new FormArray([
      new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl(null),
        value: new FormControl(null)
      })
    ...
```

В `urlParams` находятся параметры ***GET*** **запроса** и *метки*, необходимо передать параметры в `HttpParams` или 
`URLSearchParams` исключая метки.

**UPD: 1**

Удаляем метки с объекта:

```typescript
const getParams = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.urlParams.value));
    for (let i = 0 ; i < getParams.length ; i++) {
      delete getParams[i].mark;
    }
```

Как теперь передать в HttpParams новый объкт без меток для получения:

`?name=value&name2=value22&login=admin`

Пробовал так:

```typescript
let params = new HttpParams({fromObject : getParams });
```

На выходе `0=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&1=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&1=1&2=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&3=%5Bobject%20Object%5D`

[image: 0=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&1=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&1=1&2=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&3=%5Bobject%20Object%5D]

Как это правильно реализовать ?

Comment: я вам уже отвечал на этот вопрос, в конечном итоге вы пришли к тому что якобы получается неправильный урл из-за слеша или `?`, добавьте валидацию и все будет работать

Comment: @overthesanity сейчас чуть другая проблема, обновил вопрос

Comment: @overthesanity или здесь без цикла и `params.append` не обойтись ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Извиняюсь за такой говнокод, но это более декларативный подход, либо же используйте тот вариант, о котором я вам говорил ранее, используя `append`:

```ts
const urlParams = [...this.requestForm.controls.urlParams.value];

let i = urlParams.length;
const paramsArray: HttpParams[] = [];
while (i--) {
    delete urlParams[i].mark;

    // Проверяем что не `null`
    if (urlParams[i].name && urlParams[i].value) {
        paramsArray.push(new HttpParams({
            fromObject: urlParams[i]
        }));
    }
}

i = paramsArray.length;
let params = new HttpParams();
while (i--) {
    // массив ключей `['name', 'value']`
    const [name, value]: string[] = paramsArray[i].keys();
    // сеттим параметры по ключу и значению
    params = params.set(paramsArray[i].get(name), paramsArray[i].get(value));
}

console.log(params.toString());
```